# How to create a collection group index for a query on a single field in Firestore?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, get

I have written Flutter code involving Firebase and Firestore for retrieving data regarding the current user immediately after their signing-in.

My expectation was for Firestore to confirm data within Firestore, but instead Firestore has requested an index.

The problem I have is having no clue on how to produce the index being requested.

The code is as follows:

```js
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;

import '../widgets/textfield_try.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({super.key, this.onTap});

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  auth.FirebaseAuth _auth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore _dB = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Function()? onTap;
  static const source = Source.serverAndCache;

  Future<void> signUserIn() async {
    await auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
    if (_auth != null) {
      try {
        final docRef = await _dB.collectionGroup('signInData').where(
            'eAddress', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.email).get().then((
            value) {
          final userData = value.docs.toList();
          print(userData);
        });
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 37)),

              TextField_Try(
                  hintText: 'Username',
                  obscureText: false,
                  controller: emailController),

              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0)),

              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 28.0),
                  child: TextField_Try(
                    hintText: '**************',
                    obscureText: true,
                    controller: passwordController,
                  )),

              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)),

              ElevatedButton(onPressed: signUserIn, child: Text('Sign In')),

              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Flutter's response to the code is:

```
D/FirebaseAuth(12349): Notifying id token listeners about user ( ************************ ).
I/flutter (12349): [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.
```

My question is, how is an index for a collection-group query based on a single collection-id produced?

Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You're querying `collectionGroup('signInData')` so you'll need to create an index on that collection group. A collection group covers all collections with a specific name, so in your case you'd enter `signInData` as the collection ID.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a collection group index for a query on a single field? If so, I recommend updating your question title and body to make that clearer?

Comment: I have updated as you have suggested.  Thank you : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're querying `collectionGroup('signInData')`, you'll need to create an index on that collection group. In your case you need a single-field index on the `eAddress` field of the `signInData` collection group.

To do this in the Firebase console:

1. Go to the [Firestore indexes](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/indexes) page in the Firebase console
2. Click the `Single field` panel, since you want to add an index on a single field.
3. Click the <kbd>Add excemption</kbd> button near the bottom of the panel

[image]

4. Enter `signInData` in the <kbd>Collection ID</kbd> field and `eAddress` as the <kbd>Field path</kbd>.
5. **Check the <kbd>Collection group</kbd> box**

[image]

Finally: click <kbd>Next</kbd> and then <kbd>Save</kbd>

---

Here's an example of such an exemption/index I created for this use-case:

[image]

And the Dart/Flutter code that I then used to query this collection group through that index:

```dart
var group = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('signInData');
var query = group.where('eAddress', isEqualTo: 'user@acme.com');

query.get().then((querySnapshot) {
  print('Got ${querySnapshot.size} results');
  for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
    print(doc.reference);
  }
});
```

I initially tested it with JavaScript code using the modular SDK, so here's that too:

```js
let group = collectionGroup(db, 'signInData');
let q = query(group, where('eAddress', '==', 'user@acme.com'));

getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
  console.log(`Got ${querySnapshot.docs.length} results`);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.ref);
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi @Frank, many thanks for your response.  What you explained is exactly what I needed to know.  In the end, I managed to reach the point of creating an index, but it seemed to me that my only option was to create a composite one - the single field type seemed to be something different, however your explanation has made it clear to me that the exemption is also an index setting.  I'll give this a try in the morning.  Many thanks for your consideration : )

Comment: I initially got stuck too, when I tried to do what you need. I finally figured it out in the Cloud console, and then could do the same in the Firebase one too - hence the screenshots. Clearly this part of the UI is confusing. :) --- It also made me realize that apparently I'd never needed a collection group index on a single field, which was 

Comment: It's definitely a relief that you found the way and explained it.  I am unsure if I would ever have selected the other option otherwise.  What you have helped to solve will definitely benefit many other newbies to the collection-group query : ) I now hope to make new progress lol

Comment: Hi @Frank, I have just now tried the solution and I have found that despite the index being set up, that the error message requesting an index is still given.  By any chance, would you have tried the solution in my context, and do you also receive the same message, and, if "no", could you explain the difference between what we are doing please?

Comment: Yes I have. See the additional screenshot and code I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Frank.  We have the index arrangement exactly the same, so maybe the code is what I need to adjust.  Today the output was an empty list (different to yesterday), and then it was the same index-required message ... So is it the code or is it the index?

Comment: Two things noticed today: (1) there's a "query builder" setting in the Firestore UI, and by setting that up it confirms the result of the query I have created - so that I know it works.  Which means, (2) there must be something wrong in the backend somewhere, and that's what's stopping the query from giving me the result at the front end ... When I attempted to set up the Firestore CLI, an error arose saying that I did not have a Firestore database, to go and set one up, but then the link given took me to the Firestore that I have already set up.

Comment: Playing with Firestore's query-builder setting, I have found a mistake I was making ... I didn't name the collection properly, and Firestore has also made something different of the field I am selecting in its automatic creation of the index ... Hopefully this resolves, but some time for propagation first.

Comment: In the backend I confirmed the GCP location [ https://console.firebase.google.com/project/ ], and now my Firestore is found, and I also added a new API key [ https://console.developers.google.com ], and now the Firestore CLI is initialised ... There's still something wrong because there's a consistent timeout error occurring regarding the query ... I thought this would be resolved by adding in the new API key ... The result to the query switched again, from an empty list '[]' to '[Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']' ... It could mean the data is there now but needs to be accessed.

Comment: Hey @mathems32 Good to hear that you're making progress on further troubleshooting. I added an example of working Flutter code querying the index we generated - which I tested in https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zd6a064bd6b0?entry=lib%2Fmain.dart. If you have further trouble getting the code working, I recommend posting a new question with a similar repro

Comment: Hi @Frank, thank you for the confirmation and further info.  I managed to find the way to get a single field's data into a variable on Flutter yesterday evening, so I am mostly finished here.  I'll add a few photos to illustrate the alternative route to making an index and then leave things here as.  Many thanks for your support along the way.

Answer (score 7):

After hearing of the solution posted and saluted here, I noticed another way in which Firestore permits the creation of an index, and in this particular way, Firestore checks the proposed index and offers a link to create it for you automatically:

So, on the Firestore first screen, notice options to create indexes, but also notice the option to build a query (as shown in the photo below)

[image]

If you select the Query-builder option you'll be introduced to a menu that automatically incorporates your Firestore's collection and field names (as shown in the photo below)

[image]

You can add other features to the query, like the ordering of results (as shown below)

[image]

If you run the query that you are proposing and Firestore decides that that query requires an index, then Firestore will offer you a link towards having that index created for you automatically (as seen below)

[image]

Okay, so that's everything, and now you know two ways of creating an index for Firestore's collection-group queries ..... Haaaappy coding : )

Comment: There answers were very helpful. The Google documentation does not seem to suggest the use of "exception". Also when I run the sample City/Landmarks example code, it did not show the suggestion. It seems to require us going to the console's query builder.

Comment: You have just change my life, Thank you! Now i don't have to do complicated if statements.